# What features are desirable for a programming language?

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages, language-design, language-features, compilation

Recently my university has set large projects for its undergraduates. One of these projects is to create a new programming language with all of the most desirable parts of other languages. Now, I know that many things would be pretty infeasible for me to implement efficiently (or even closely) - making the language very close to natural language for example.

There are some neat features that would be nice, like high order functions and an operator for swapping the value of two variables. However I am struggling to think of very many, so some suggestions would be very much appreciated - the best one gets marked as the answer. I am only looking for ideas here though, not methods for how to implement them.

Comment: Whilst you have criteria for acceptance of an answer, this remains pretty subjective.

Comment: I think you have it the wrong way around. You find problems to solve, and if you can't do it in other languages (unlikely) you make your own to do it. Even if you can do it in other languages, your best bet is to find problems you have first and the solution becomes much more organic.

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question because it is too general. Someone might like minimalism (Scheme), or a language that may have too many features (C++). Or perhaps one may just want a domain-specific language (PHP) to tackle a specific problem.

Comment: Give them [LOLCODE](http://lolcode.com)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Features I like:

- associative arrays so I can do things like `price["apple"] := 0.99`
- for-each loops so I don't have to worry about indexing non-existant elements of a collection
- the `:=` operator for assignment, instead of `=` ;)
- switch-case statements that allow for things other than numeric values, eg: `case "apple": price := 0.99`.
- ranges of numbers/dates as a valid datatype.
- functions having named parameters and default values
- native support for regex operations (like Perl)

Comment: No `:=` operator. Most langs just have `=` for assignment and `==` for comparison. And `:=` looks really, really ugly :)

Comment: I had to look up what `:=` means, and I like it!

Comment: @Radek S: well sure, but it's *my* answer and *I* like it. I think assignment should have an operator that is more different than the comparison operator. and `==` can look like `=` when one is tired... ;)

Comment: := seems like a good one as the = operator for assignment just seems to contradict the idea of equality that we are brought up understanding.

Comment: `:=` Pacal worst language ever, they force you to learn this in school.

Comment: @jcubic: I never used Pascal. I got this from Eiffel and PL/SQL.

Comment: That's why I don't like PL/SQL. I was learning this when I was a student, and this was nightmare. No documentation, Bad error messages that tell you nothing, language don't allow you to do what you want. I don't know why someone may like this. And I never program in Eiffel.

Comment: @jcubic: PL/SQL is a bit of a niche but it definitely has some good points too, it's good for applications that need very close integration with the database, I wouldn't use it as a general-purpose programming language. I agree that the documentation could be better. It seems strange to hate a language just because it has an operator for assignment that you don't like, but... meh.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Inheritance would be nice...though it's not available in any current languages.

Comment: err, what ? c++ isn't a current language I guess.

Comment: Python also supports MI.

Answer (score 0):

The most powerful one:

- Dynamic Types
- Language that don't hide anything
- Functions as first class citizens. (which allow to use functional programming)
- Runtime introspection
- Language allow to overdrive default functions and object.
- Meta programming
- Dynamic Code generation
- Extending Language in this language (only lisp have this)

Answer (score 0):

At present, I'm yearning for a language feature like JavaScript eval, with the additional power that it would execute the eval'ed instruction sequence:

```
execute_THIS( a += b; c = myfunc(a); if c < 0 exit(); );
```

That is, the language run-time could interpret and execute statements written in the language.

-- p

Comment: Lisp macros do this. They are basically something like functions that return lisp code that is executed. Most powerful feature allow to extend lisp in lisp.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I'd forgotten Lisp. Good catch!

Comment: There are actually a lot of languages that provide this functionality. It's fairly common in dynamic languages, and not unheard of compiled ones (though the compiled ones generally need to include a compiler/interp in the end result in order to support it).